# Google map event listener for "grouped" polyline and markers

Tags: google-maps

I am creating a google map for hiking. Each individual hike is displayed by a polyline. Each individual hike also has a start location and end location (at either end of the polyline). The start and end locations are each displayed by a marker (NOT a symbol). I have spent hours trying to add functionality such that when there is a mouseover event over EITHER the polyline OR either of the markers then both the polyline and both markers will "react" (in this case the opacity will change).

I have spent hours trying to find the solution. The closest I have got is the code below. In the code below, only if the mouse moves over the polyline will the polyline and markers react. But if the mouse moves over either marker, the polyline and markers do not react. I do understand my code is incorrect, but I cannot get closer to the solution.

I guess I somehow need to "group" each polyline and the respective 2 markers to one "object", "variable" or "layer" - but I simply cannot work this out.

Please note, the code below is simplified for only one marker (start location) per polyline (hike).

(At top of the code below is the gpx file from which the polyline and markers are created. Copy the gpx data into file and name google.gpx)

```
//start of the trimmed gpx data. Copy to new file and save as google.gpx
<lines>
    <trkseg>
        <trkpt lat="-33.879843" lng="151.225769"/>
        <trkpt lat="-33.869843" lng="151.245769"/>
        <trkpt lat="-33.859843" lng="151.255769"/>
    </trkseg>
    <trkseg>
        <trkpt lat="-33.869843" lng="151.265769"/>
        <trkpt lat="-33.869843" lng="151.275769"/>
    </trkseg>
</lines>
//end of the trimmed gpx data

<style>
    #map {
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
    function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.863276, 151.207977),
      zoom: 12
    });

        downloadUrl('google.gpx', function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var trkseg = xml.querySelectorAll("trkseg");

            for (var l = 0; l < trkseg.length; l++) {
                var path = [],
                trkPoints = trkseg[l].querySelectorAll('trkpt');

                for (var p = 0; p < trkPoints.length; p++) {
                    var trkpt = trkPoints[p],
                    lat = parseFloat(trkpt.getAttribute("lat")),
                    lng = parseFloat(trkpt.getAttribute("lng")),
                    point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                    path.push(point);
                }

                var trkptMarker = trkPoints[0];
                var startMarkerLat = parseFloat(trkptMarker.getAttribute("lat"));
                var startMarkerLng = parseFloat(trkptMarker.getAttribute("lng"));
                var startMarkerLatLng = {lat: startMarkerLat, lng: startMarkerLng};
                var startIcon = 'https://stunninghikes.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/hike_start_pin_circular-e1534182115238.png';
                var startIconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(startIcon);

                var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: path,
                    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                    strokeWeight: 2,

                    startMarker: new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: startMarkerLatLng,
                        map: map,
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        icon: startIconImage,
                        zIndex: 10
                    }),
                });

                polyline.setMap(map);

                google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'mouseover', function(event) {
                    this.get('startMarker').setOptions({
                        opacity: 1.0,
                    });
                    this.setOptions({
                        strokeColor: '#128934',
                        strokeOpacity: 1,
                        strokeWeight: 5,
                    });
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'mouseout', function(event) {
                    this.get('startMarker').setOptions({
                        opacity: 0.5,
                    });
                    this.setOptions({
                        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                        strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                        strokeWeight: 2
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }

  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  } 

  function doNothing() {}
</script>

<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GOOGLEKEY&&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option given your existing code is to add the equivalent mouseover/mouseout listeners to the marker:

```
var startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: startMarkerLatLng,
  map: map,
  opacity: 0.5,
  icon: startIconImage,
  zIndex: 10
});
var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: path,
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 0.5,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  map: map,
  startMarker: startMarker
});
startMarker.set("polyline", polyline);

google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'mouseover', function(event) {
  this.get('startMarker').setOptions({
    opacity: 1.0,
  });
  this.setOptions({
    strokeColor: '#128934',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 5,
  });
});

google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'mouseout', function(event) {
  this.get('startMarker').setOptions({
    opacity: 0.5,
  });
  this.setOptions({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
});
google.maps.event.addListener(startMarker, 'mouseover', function(event) {
  this.setOptions({
    opacity: 1.0,
  });
  this.get("polyline").setOptions({
    strokeColor: '#128934',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 5,
  });
});

google.maps.event.addListener(startMarker, 'mouseout', function(event) {
  this.setOptions({
    opacity: 0.5,
  });
  this.get("polyline").setOptions({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bketrgpj/5/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var xml = parseXml(xmlStr);
  var trkseg = xml.querySelectorAll("trkseg");

  for (var l = 0; l < trkseg.length; l++) {
    var path = [],
      trkPoints = trkseg[l].querySelectorAll('trkpt');

    for (var p = 0; p < trkPoints.length; p++) {
      var trkpt = trkPoints[p],
        lat = parseFloat(trkpt.getAttribute("lat")),
        lng = parseFloat(trkpt.getAttribute("lng")),
        point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
      path.push(point);
      bounds.extend(point);
    }

    var trkptMarker = trkPoints[0];
    var startMarkerLat = parseFloat(trkptMarker.getAttribute("lat"));
    var startMarkerLng = parseFloat(trkptMarker.getAttribute("lng"));
    var startMarkerLatLng = {
      lat: startMarkerLat,
      lng: startMarkerLng
    };
    var startIcon = 'https://stunninghikes.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/hike_start_pin_circular-e1534182115238.png';
    var startIconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage(startIcon);
    var startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: startMarkerLatLng,
      map: map,
      opacity: 0.5,
      icon: startIconImage,
      zIndex: 10
    });
    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: path,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.5,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      map: map,
      startMarker: startMarker
    });
    startMarker.set("polyline", polyline);

    google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'mouseover', function(event) {
      this.get('startMarker').setOptions({
        opacity: 1.0,
      });
      this.setOptions({
        strokeColor: '#128934',
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 5,
      });
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'mouseout', function(event) {
      this.get('startMarker').setOptions({
        opacity: 0.5,
      });
      this.setOptions({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.5,
        strokeWeight: 2
      });
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(startMarker, 'mouseover', function(event) {
      this.setOptions({
        opacity: 1.0,
      });
      this.get("polyline").setOptions({
        strokeColor: '#128934',
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 5,
      });
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(startMarker, 'mouseout', function(event) {
      this.setOptions({
        opacity: 0.5,
      });
      this.get("polyline").setOptions({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.5,
        strokeWeight: 2
      });
    });

  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function parseXml(str) {
  if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('MicrosoftXMLDOM');
    doc.loadXML(str);
    return doc;
  } else if (window.DOMParser) {
    return (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
  }
}
var xmlStr = '<lines><trkseg><trkpt lat="-33.879843" lng="151.225769"/><trkpt lat="-33.869843" lng="151.245769"/><trkpt lat="-33.859843" lng="151.255769"/></trkseg><trkseg><trkpt lat="-33.869843" lng="151.265769"/><trkpt lat="-33.869843" lng="151.275769"/></trkseg></lines>';
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you SO much. Very much appreciated.